# How to compare dotnet packages and txt

Tags: powershell

I have the script:

$Test = (dotnet list C:\Tasks.Api.csproj package) and it provides some packages (WITH 2 SPACES ON THE END!):

```
Project 'Tasks.Api' has the following package references 
   [net5.0]:  
   Top-level Package                               Requested   Resolved 
   > AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer             6.0.0       6.0.0    
   > Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore      2.18.0      2.18.0   
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools           5.0.11      5.0.11   
   > Swashbuckle.AspNetCore                        6.2.3       6.2.3
 (SPACE)
 (SPACE)
```

gettype provide next:

[image]

Then I have a "good" file (txt):

```
AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore
```

Now I want to know, does my "good" file contains lines from $Test or not?

I think I tried millions of other options, but now I'm stuck on it:

```
$whiteliste = Get-Content C:\whitelist.txt 
$test = (dotnet list C:\Tasks.Api.csproj package) 
$array = @() 
$test[3..($test.Length-2)] | foreach { 
$array+=$_ 
} 
Foreach ($item in $array) { 
Write-host "!!!" $item 
$containsWord = $whiteliste | %{$_ -contains $item.Remove(" ")} 
if ($containsWord -contains $true) { 
    Write-Host "There is!" 
} else { 
    Write-Host "There ins't!" 
} 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: use `-like` or `-match` instead of `-contains`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without getting fancy, a simple solution would be to use the `-Match` operator to find those package references seeing as they're unique names, and we can make use of some *user friendly* RegEx:

```
$whiteliste = (Get-Content -Path "C:\whitelist.txt").Foreach{[regex]::Escape($_.Trim())} -join "|"
$test.Foreach{
    if ($_ -match $whiteliste) {
        Write-Host -Object "Found: [$($Matches[0])]"
    }
}
```

**Edit**: *Based on your comment on Santi's post, if you would like it to tell you if there is no matches found, you can add a Begin, Process, and End clause:*

```
$test.ForEach{
    Begin { $Matches = $null }
    Process { 
        if ($_ -match $tomatch) { 
            Write-Host -Object "Found: $($Matches[0])" 
        } 
    }
    End { 
        if ($null -eq $Matches) { 
            "No Match Found:(" 
        } 
    }
}
```

- First, the *Begin* clause will set the automatic variable of `$matches` to `$null`; *this way it doesn't interfere with past matches*.
- Then, the *Process* clause will run your code to add to `$matches`.
- Finally, the *End* clause will check to see if `$matches` was populated and if it wasn't, output that nothing was found.

  - This is is doable since `-match` will populate the `$matches` variable when something is found.
  - If nothing is found, the variable won't be populated.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) for checking this, [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators) will only work with **exact matches** of an array.

Here is a minimal example:

```sh
$test = dotnet list C:\Tasks.Api.csproj package
$good = Get-Content goodfile.txt

foreach($i in $test) {
    foreach($z in $good) {
        if($i -match $z) {
            "I've got a match!!! [ $i ]"
            # no need to keep comparing, `break` the inner loop
            break 
        }
    }
}
```

Which would result in:

```
I've got a match!!! [ > AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer             6.0.0       6.0.0 ]
I've got a match!!! [ > Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore      2.18.0      2.18.0 ]
```

Another great alternative would be using [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-like-and--notlike) and adding [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.2) to the RHS of the comparison, as pointed out by [shadow2020](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11059320/shadow2020) in his helpful comment:

```sh
if($i -like "*$z*") {
    "I've got a match!!! [ $i ]"
    break
}
```

Following your last comment, how can we add a comment if there was no match:

```sh
:outer foreach($i in $test) {
    # if this line is only white space, skip it
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($i)) {
        continue
    }
    
    foreach($z in $good) {
        if($i -match $z) {
            "I've got a match!!! [ $i ]"
            # no need to keep comparing,
            # `continue` with the next element of the outer loop
            continue outer
        }
    }

    # if we're here, no element of `$good`
    # was matched with all elements of `$test`
    "Couldn't find a match for [ $i ]"
}
```

The result of this would be:

```
Couldn't find a match for [ [net5.0]: ]
Couldn't find a match for [ Top-level Package                               Requested   Resolved ]
I've got a match!!! [ > AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer             6.0.0       6.0.0 ]
I've got a match!!! [ > Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore      2.18.0      2.18.0 ]
Couldn't find a match for [ > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools           5.0.11      5.0.11 ]
Couldn't find a match for [ > Swashbuckle.AspNetCore                        6.2.3       6.2.3 ]
```

See [**Using a labeled continue in a loop**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.2#using-a-labeled-continue-in-a-loop) which describes and explains the use of `continue outer` in this example.

Comment: thx! works fine, but if I added else {"no match"} is starting for some reasons duplicate package names. Any ideas?

Comment: @nobodyfromhell the logic for adding a "no match" would be a bit different using this method, there wouldn't be any `else` condition tho. I can add an example if you want

Comment: Santiago Squarzon if you can - it will be amazing!

Comment: @nobodyfromhell see my last update :)

Comment: thx man! all the best!